# Change the day in month on an NSDate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

The code below adds or subtracts a month from a date. After that operation I want to explicitly set the day of the month to 15. How can I achieve this?

```
NSDateComponents* offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
int magnitude = isLeft ? 1 : -1;
[offsetComponents setMonth:magnitude];
NSCalendar* calendar1 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
updatedDate = [calendar1 dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:dateRef options:0];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setting of the month is irrelevant and a separate operation. Get the components of the date, change the day, then recompose the date. You can do this either before or after you change the month.

```
NSDate * today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar * cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents * offsetComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
[offsetComponents setMonth:-1];

// Either

NSDate * sameDayLastMonth = [cal dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents
                                                 toDate:today
                                                options:0];

NSDateComponents * lastMonthComps = [cal components:NSUIntegerMax
                                           fromDate:sameDayLastMonth];
[lastMonthComps setDay:15];

NSDate * fifteenthOfLastMonth = [cal dateFromComponents:lastMonthComps];

// or

NSDateComponents * todayComps = [cal components:NSUIntegerMax
                                       fromDate:today];
[todayComps setDay:15];

NSDate * fifteenth = [cal dateFromComponents:todayComps];

NSDate * fifteenthOfLastMonth = [cal dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents
                                                     toDate:fifteenth
                                                    options:0];
```

---

Or, even easier (duh, I should've done this in the first place):

```
NSDate * today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar * cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSInteger offset = arc4random_uniform(2) ? -1 : 1;

NSDateComponents * comps = [cal components:NSUIntegerMax
                                  fromDate:today];
[comps setDay:15];
[comps setMonth:[comps month] + offset];

NSDate * newDate = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
```